# Having trouble with headers

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to C, and am having an issue with my header file structure. It seems that when I include `keyboard.h` from `ps2.h`, since `keyboard.h` originally included `ps2.h` first, `ps2.h` cannot access `keyboard.h`'s definitions.

**keyboard.h**

```
#ifndef KEYBOARD
#define KEYBOARD

#include "ps2.h"

typedef enum {
    KEY_UNDEFINED,

    // letters
    A,
    B,
    ... many more keys
} Key;

typedef enum {
    TYPE_UNDEFINED, PRESSED, RELEASED
} KeyEventType;

typedef struct {
    Key key;
    KeyEventType type;
} KeyEvent;

#define NULL {KEY_UNDEFINED, TYPE_UNDEFINED}

... function declarations, implemented in a keyboard.c file next to keyboard.h

#endif
```

**ps2.h**

```
#ifndef PS2
#define PS2

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "keyboard.h"

#define keycount 17

KeyEvent scanCodeSet1[] = { NULL, { ESCAPE, PRESSED },
    { DIGIT1, PRESSED }, { DIGIT2, PRESSED }, 
    ... many more codes
};
```

I include `keyboard.h` in my main file.

So like I said above, all the definitions (such as `RELEASED`) accessed from `ps2.h` don't work.

The many error messages fit this pattern:

```
'PRESSED' undeclared here (not in a function)
```

I'm using GCC if that helps.

Comment: you have a circular dependency here. why do you need two headers include each other?

Comment: Because `ps2.h` calls functions in `keyboard.h` and the other way around.

Comment: No, code in headers usually don't call functions, they are should be just declarations.

Comment: I am using header guards.

Comment: My `keyboard.c` calls stuff in `ps2.c`.

Comment: then include ps2.h in keyboard.c, not in keyboard.h

Comment: @user3528438 That fixed it, thanks.

Comment: In `keyboard.h` you include `ps2.h` before you declare the types used by `ps2.h`. The compiler is correct when it reports them as undeclared because it didn't parse the part of `keyboard.h` where you declare them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a major problem in your `keyboard.h` file:

```
#define NULL {KEY_UNDEFINED, TYPE_UNDEFINED}
```

You should not redefine `NULL`.  It is defined in the standard library include files and it is very important to not provide a conflicting definition such as this one.

Regarding the include order issue: this is what is happening:

- You include `"keyboard.h"`
- `keyboard.h` defines `KEYBOARD`
- `keyboard.h` includes `"ps2.h"`
- `ps2.h` defines `PS2`
- it includes `"keyboard.h"` recursively
- `keyboard.h` checks if `KEYBOARD` is defined, it is, the contents is not parsed.
- `ps2.h` defines `scanCodeSet1` with symbols from `keyboard.h` that have not been defined yet because the recursive inclusion was skipped and the enclosing parse of `keyboard.h` has not seen them yet.

You can correct this problem by either:

- not including `ps2.h` from `keyboard.h`
- moving the inclusion of `ps2.h` after the definitions that are required there.
- include both headers from the C files.

It is not a good idea to have 2 include files include one another, you should reorganize your definitions to avoid that:

- use a single header file
- use a third header file included by both `keyboard.h` and `ps2.h` that defines the symbols needed by both.